# SQL JOIN tables based on values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm struggeling with the following:

I have two tables:

**table_1:**

```
kalib_name  var_name  y_0  y_1  y_2  ...  y_10
```

and

**table_2:**

```
var_name
```

I now want to construct a table, where for every kalib_name there are all var_name form **table_2**, even if the combination kalib_name var_name doesn't exist in **table_1** and fill the other columns (y_0 ... y_10) with NULL or 0.
I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT table_2.[var_name] AS variable_name
    FROM table_2
    WHERE table_2.[var_name] IS NOT NULL) AS A
LEFT JOIN table_1
ON (A.variable_name = table_1.[var_name])
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I have 69 distinct values in table_2 and 101 distinct kalib_names. I would expect to get an table from the length 69*101, mine is however only about 3800 entries long.

Comment: do it with cross join MG92

Comment: @zip how do I perform a cross join on selected columns, but still get the data of the other columns I didn't use for the cross join? I know i can use `SELECT *
FROM (select var_name from table_2) b, (select kalib_name from table_1) c;` but I still need the values from y_0 ... y_10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a combination of a cross join for all combination pairs and then `LEFT JOIN` to pull in data in existing pairs wrapped in `NZ()` for `NULL` to zero handling:

```
SELECT pairs.kalib_name, pairs.var_name, 
       NZ(table1.y_0) AS y_0,
       NZ(table1.y_1) AS y_1,
       NZ(table1.y_2) AS y_2,
       NZ(table1.y_3) AS y_3,
       ...
       NZ(table1.y_10) AS y_10,
FROM 

  (SELECT t1.kalib_name, t2.var_name
   FROM (select distinct kalib_name from table1
         where kalib_name is not null) AS t1, 
        (select distinct var_name from table2 
         where var_name is not null) AS t2
  ) pairs

LEFT JOIN table1
   ON pairs.[kalib_name] = table1.[kalib_name]
   AND pairs.[var_name] = table1.[var_name]
```

Comment: I had to adapt the Query a little, but this is essentially what im using.

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, adapt according to needs. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

That's plain old-style cartesian product :

SELECT kalib_name, table_2.var_name
  FROM table_1, table_2 ;

Comment: Won't this also cross-product the columns y_0 ... y_10 with table_2?

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`:

```
select t2.var_name, . . .   -- the other columns you want
from table2 as t2 left join
     table1 as t1
     on t2.var_name = t1.kalib_name;
```

EDIT:

If you want a cross product, then in MS Access you use a comma (it doesn't support `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select t1.var_name, t1.kalib_name
from (select distinct var_name from table_2) as t2,
     (select distinct kalib_name from table_1) as t1;
```

Comment: This does exactly the same as the code I used. It ensures that there is every var_name from t1, but I need to link every kalib_name in t1 to every var_name in t2.

Comment: @MG92 . . . I think  I misunderstood your question.  You *want* a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get one entry for each table_1 - table_2 combination with the other columns you want present set to 0:

```
SELECT table_1.kalib_name, table_2.var_name, 0 AS y_0, 0 AS y_1, ..., 0 AS y_10 FROM table_1, table_2
```

If you want one entry for each unique combination add DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_1.kalib_name, table_2.var_name, 0 AS y_0, 0 AS y_1, ..., 0 AS y_10 FROM table_1, table_2
```